# React useImperativeHandle when element is null

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use this [npm package](https://github.com/azmenak/material-ui-nested-menu-item/blob/master/src/index.tsx) for nested menus in Material UI, but it does not compile for me because of this line

```
  // error
  const menuItemRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null)
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => menuItemRef.current)

  // yet this is ok?
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useImperativeHandle(containerRefProp, () => containerRef.current)
```

It complains

> Type 'HTMLLIElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLLIElement'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLLIElement'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1089, 79): The expected type comes from the return type of
> this signature. (property) React.RefObject.current:
> HTMLLIElement | null

While I understand the issue, I don't know what to do. I can't even understand the description of `useImperativeHandle`

Comment: i dont understand, this code is yours or this code is inside this npm package?

Comment: It is in the linked package. I can skirt around this by doing `as HTMLLIElement`. I just can't understand refs. How can they be set to null and then never set again, but be useful elsewhere?

Comment: What do the declaration of ref and containerRefProp look like? Do you still have errors if you remove the first useImperativeHandle?

Comment: No but then the code does not work. Adding `as HTMLLIElement` works enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to type cast the `current` with `as HTMLLIElement`

```
const menuItemRef = useRef<HTMLLIElement>(null)
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => menuItemRef.current as HTMLLIElement)
```

Maybe helpful to someone.